# Dynamic SQLAlchemy ORM relationship generation

Tags: python-3.x, orm, sqlalchemy, factory

**Premise**: I have a *lot* of tables that have to individually created (they cannot be dynamically created) and therefore, I find myself constantly having to make mixins that allow the standardization of relating tables:

```
class A_Table(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

class A_Relator(My_Mixin_Base):
    @declared_attr
    def a_table_id(cls):
        return Column(ForeignKey(A_Table.id))

    @declared_attr
    def a_table(cls):
        return relationship(A_Table)

class B_Table(A_Relator, Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

class C_Table(A_Relator, Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

class D_Table(A_Relator, Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

# ad nauseam
```

Simple, but when `B_Table`, `C_Table`, etc. all have their own Relator classes, it gets very repetitive, and thus, something that should be easily solved in code.

**My Solution**: I made a class factory (?) that creates a mixin class to be used one time.

```
def related(clss, defined=False, altName=None):
    class X((Definer if defined else Relator),):
        linkedClass = clss

        @classmethod
        def linkedClassFieldName(cls):
            return "{}Id".format(clss.getBackrefName())

        def linkId(cls):
            return Column(ForeignKey(clss.id))

        def linkRe(cls):
            return relationship(clss,
                                foreign_keys=getattr(cls, "{}Id".format(clss.getBackrefName() if not altName else altName)),
                                backref=cls.getBackrefName())

    setattr(X, "{}Id".format(clss.getBackrefName() if not altName else altName), declared_attr(X.linkId))
    setattr(X,   "{}".format(clss.getBackrefName() if not altName else altName), declared_attr(X.linkRe))
    del X.linkId
    del X.linkRe

    return X
```

Which allows you to do the following and be done with it:

```
class B_Table(related(A_Table), Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
```

...but this is messy and confusing, and I would guess there is a much better way to do this that leaves a lot less to uncertainty.

**Question**: I'm looking for a way to do this in a more direct SQLAlchemy-aligned way with less roundabout "hack". Or in summary: how do I make a generic SQLAlchemy mixin that generates a relationship?

Comment: Hi. In your first block of example code, the `ForeignKey` and `relationship` in your `A_Relator` class are defined back to your `A_Table` model right? In your example code they are related back to model `A` which isn't defined.

Comment: @SuperShoot Yes, sorry, you're correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a mess around with this. Not sure how well this solution will suit your needs but I did it as more of a learning exercise for myself, and if it helps for you, then great.

So with the objective to be able to have foreign keys and relationships defined on models with as little input as possible, this is what I came up with.

Here are the models that I used:

```
class Base:
    @declared_attr
    def __tablename__(cls):
        return cls.__name__.lower()

    @declared_attr
    def id(cls):
        return Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<{type(self).__name__}(id={self.id})>'

Base = declarative_base(cls=Base)

class A_Table(Base):
    parents = []

class B_Table(Base):
    parents = ['A_Table']

class C_Table(Base):
    parents = ['A_Table', 'B_Table']
```

Notice the class variable `parents` on each model which is a sequence of strings that should be other model names that inherit from the same `declarative_base` instance. Foreign keys and relationships to the parent classes will be created on the class that declares them as parents.

So then leveraging off of the fact that:

> Attributes may be added to the class after its construction, and they
>   will be added to the underlying Table and mapper() definitions as
>   appropriate

(see [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/declarative/basic_use.html#defining-attributes))

I iterate through all of the models that are defined on `Base` and build the required objects according to the parents it's given and plug them in.

Here's the function that does all of that:

```
from sqlalchemy import inspect  # this would be the only new import you'd need

def relationship_builder(Base):
    """ Finds all models defined on Base, and constructs foreign key
    columns and relationships on each as per their defined parent classes.

    """

    def make_fk_col(parent):
        """ Constructs a Column of the same type as the primary
        key of the parent and establishes it as a foreign key.
        Constructs a name for the foreign key column and attribute.

        """
        parent_pk = inspect(parent).primary_key[0]
        fk_name = f'{parent.__name__}_{parent_pk.name}'
        col = Column(
            fk_name, parent_pk.type,
            ForeignKey(f'{parent.__tablename__}.{parent_pk.name}')
        )
        return fk_name, col

    # this bit gets all the models that are defined on Base and maps them to
    # their class name.
    models = {
        cls.__name__: cls  for cls in Base._decl_class_registry.values() if
        hasattr(cls, '__tablename__')
    }

    for model in models.values():
        for parentname in model.parents:
            parent = models.get(parentname)
            if parent is not None:
                setattr(model, *make_fk_col(parent))
                rel = relationship(parent, backref=model.__name__)
                setattr(model, parentname, rel)
```

To test, this is just at the bottom of the same module that I've got everything else defined in:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    relationship_builder(Base)
    a = A_Table(id=1)
    b = B_Table(id=1)
    c = C_Table(id=1)
    a.B_Table.append(b)
    a.C_Table.append(c)
    b.C_Table.append(c)
    print(b.A_Table)
    print(c.A_Table)
    print(c.B_Table)
# <A_Table(id=1)>
# <A_Table(id=1)>
# <B_Table(id=1)>
```

Here's the schema it created:

[image: Schema produced]

This won't work for composite primary/foreign keys but I don't think it would be too much of a stretch to get it there. If `len(inspect(parent).primary_keys) > 1` you'd need to build `ForeignKeyConstraints` and add them to the table definition, but I haven't tested that at all.

I also don't think it would be too much of a stretch to make it fully automated if you could name your models in such a manner that the subordination of a model could be inferred from the name of the model itself. Again, just thinking out loud.